# Execute Immediate Loop PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested, combinations, execute

Can I use "execute immediate" with for cycle?
I need of generate a combinations of values in pl/sql.
About this I'm thinking of call a series of  nested dynamics for cycle.

Example:
column 1 have this values: A,B
column 2 have this values: C,D,E

I would like to generate this combination: 
AC / AD/ AE/ BC / BD /BE

I'm thinking to obtain this like:

```
for i in 1..count.column1
   for j in 1..count.column2
       dbms_output.put_line(column1.value(i)||'-'||column1.value(j));
end loop;
end loop;
```

Due to I don't know the number of column  (variable),
Can I use a execute immediate?

```
declare
sql_stmt varchar2(200);
begin

sql_stmt := 'for i in 1..count.column1 for j in 1..count.column2 dbms_output.put_line(column1.value(i)||'-'||column1.value(j)); end loop; end loop';
execute immediate sql_stmt;

end;
```

But I have error ORA-06512.
How can i make this? :)

Thank you in advance for your suggestion!

Comment: Not easily. `execute immediate` processes complete SQL statements and PL/SQL blocks, and these don't share variable scope with the calling procedure. You would have to generate the whole `declare ... begin ... end;` block, pass in your bind variables and pass out the result as an array or ref cursor. Also, generating statements in batch like this tends to shred Oracle's cursor cache.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this slowly in PL/SQL using nested loops, you don't need anything to be dynamic.  You'd just want

```
for i in (select distinct column1
            from your_table)
loop
  for j in (select distinct column2
              from your_table)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line( i.column1 || j.column2 );
  end loop;
end loop;
```

In the vast majority of cases, though, you'd be better off doing this in SQL

```
with col1 as (
  select distinct col1 val
    from your_table
),
col2 as (
  select distinct col2 val
    from your_table
)
select col1.val || col2.val
  from col1
       cross join col2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily get the combinations using this select statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1, t2.col2
  FROM table_name t1, table_name t2;
```